# Changing the workspace name when using WireCloud with KeyStone

Tags: fiware, keystone, fiware-wirecloud

After integrating KeyStone with WireCloud, the workspaces and the usernames look like the user name plus an id. Is there a way to configure KeyStone and/or WireCloud to only allow unique user names so that this id would not be neccessary?

This seems only to happen, if a user name is already in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `id` is appended to the username by `python-social-auth`, you can change any of the [username generation settings](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/configuration/settings.html#username-generation) used by this module. In this regard, you can use `SOCIAL_AUTH_UUID_LENGTH = 0` to remove those ids, but then WireCloud will associate new IdM accounts to previously existing users with the same username.